Move Point in a XY chart
I want to know which cell contains the value of the selected point of an xy graph
I want to change de value of a point to move it in the graph.
I want to move a point in a XY graph down or under after select it. So knowing the index point maybe I could reference it to the cells tha contain de Y value of the point

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
